# Using Google API's to get optimal path between multiple locations

Tags: java, android, navigation, maps, google-api

I am searching for some way of using any Google API or `android` framework namespace, to get an `optimized` path between `multiple` `locations`.

For exemple, we have a few `locations` within the US : Los Angeles, New York, San Francisco, Washington, San Jose. 
The order is quite bad, we arent going to go from LA to NY then back to SF and SJ.

Ive seen somewhere in the `Google Maps API V3` some unofficial way of getting the optimized order.

Is there any possible way of doing so by using exclusively `Java`, and `Android` or Google API's ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see that any Location has the Method [distanceTo(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29)?

You could write a simple Comarator like this:

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator<Location>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Location object1, Location object2) {
        return (int)object1.distanceTo(object2);
    }
}
```

Not tested and the comparsion won't return negative values, but it should work. You can then sort your Collection of Locations with

```
Collections.sort(locationCollection, new LocationComparator());
```

Comment: Do you not have knowledge of any other way of doing this ? If there isnt, then yes, this is how I am going to proceed. The only thing is, the problem is NP hard. So that N! for testing all possibilities. Ill wait a little more, and if I dont find any other way, ill mark your reply as correct. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with this site , maybe help you. It is an online tool for measuring the optimal path between multiple locations .

http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Of course I am searching for something that can calculate optimal distance between multiple destination (Traveling Salesman Problem) .

Good Luck

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling :The link is the exact thing that he/she looking for it , I can not copy the Google map here !! And sorry I don't have enough reputation to leaving a comment friend! :)

Comment: From just looking at the answer, it's not clear that it's an online tool to do this. You could perhaps mention this, and briefly summarize the features. But, that said, this answer probably doesn't really answer the question, which asks for a Java / Android / Google API way of doing it (perhaps it's possible to interact with this tool, or use the code from it, but the details of this needs to be given if that's what you're getting at). A useful answer or two should get you to the required 50 reputation to post a comment in no time.

Comment: @Dukeling: thank you very much for your guidness through best answering .